# Time conversion with xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have XML with contains time as String `Wed Apr 22 02:49:26 2015`.

```
<sample>
 <time>Wed Apr 22 02:49:26 2015</time>
</sample>
```

I need to subtract this time from current time and display on the xslt as `22:30:36`

Is there a way to do this? Appreciate if you can help me

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? Also please clarify the expected result when the difference exceeds 24 hours.

Comment: sorry i couldn't reply . my machine was crashed. i am using javax processor. actually i need to calculate the time duration that is how long i have spent. <time> gives the time i started to work. so i need the time duration i spent. so i need to substract that time from current time and  i need to get the hours minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates or times, so this is difficult. Even getting the current date or time by itself is problematic - although most XSLT 1.0 processors support an extension function for this purpose.

The more elegant solution would probably be writing your own extension function (in Java) to do this task - see: https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ext-functions

Here I will show how to do this purely in XSLT 1.0 (with the exception of getting the current date and time - which could also be passed to the stylesheet as a parameter at runtime).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/sample">
    <duration>
        <xsl:call-template name="elapsed-time">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="time" />
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </duration>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="elapsed-time">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>

    <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring($start, 5, 3)" />

    <xsl:variable name="JDN1">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="substring($start, 9, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="substring($start, 21, 4)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="hour" select="substring($start, 12, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="minute" select="substring($start, 15, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="second" select="substring($start, 18, 2)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="today" select="date:date()" />
    <xsl:variable name="now" select="date:time()" />

    <xsl:variable name="JDN2">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="substring($today, 1, 4)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="substring($today, 6, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="substring($today, 9, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="hour" select="substring($now, 1, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="minute" select="substring($now, 4, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="second" select="substring($now, 7, 2)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="$JDN2 - $JDN1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($seconds div 3600)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="r" select="$seconds mod 3600"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($r div 60)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="$r mod 60"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($h, format-number($m, ':00'), format-number($s, ':00'))"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <xsl:param name="hour"/>
    <xsl:param name="minute"/>
    <xsl:param name="second"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="jd" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:value-of select="86400*$jd + 3600*$hour + 60*$minute + $second" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the above is applied to your example input on 2015-05-21 at 11:51:48, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<duration>705:02:22</duration>
```

**Note**: it is assumed your input date format uses 2 digits for the day portion; otherwise you will need to use a different method to parse it.